# How to bring an control to front without Grid or Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this color zone on my MainWindow on the top, and below it there is a ContentControl that load a UserControl (A tab control in this case). I want for the color zone to be in front to get something like this (the white = a tab):

[image]

I searched and apparently I must change the Zindex property as long as they are in the same grid/canvas which is not the case here.

Comment: if they are not in the same grid/canvas, you will have to change the grid/canvases z-indexes

Comment: Where's the green thing come from and what do you have as markup for all this?  You have a tabcontrol and rather than using the tab header for your green part, you want to display that from a usercontrol which is where? In the content of one of the tabs? Or somewhere else?  One answer might be to define whatever the green bit is - label or whatever - inside the same grid as the contentcontrol and later on in the XAML so it has a  higher z-order implicitly.